# venvで同じ名前のディレクトリに作った仮想環境は同一の環境になりますか？

Tags: python, python3, python-venv

Windows powershellを使って構築をしようと思うのですが、
Desktop\file1\env、Desktop\file2\envという2種類のファイルに同じ名前の仮想環境のファイルを作った時、
file1\env\Scripts\python.exe・・・① file2\env\Scripts\python.exe・・・②
同じ名前をつけると同じ仮想環境となるのでしょうか？(例えば①にAモジュールを追加した時，②にもAモジュールは追加されるというように)

Answer (score 3):

異なる仮想環境になります。そのため、パッケージも別になります。

参考：各環境を実際に作成し、 `activate` したあと、以下のワンライナーを実行すると現在の `python` がどの環境のものなのかを表示することが出来ます。

`python3 -c "import sys, os; print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))"`